# Does LINUX has a full form?

Tags: linux, terminology

Some websites mention that the full form of LINUX is "Lovable Intellect Not Using Xp". If that is true, what is the meaning of Xp here? Here are the websites that mention this full form: [1](https://www.abbreviations.com/term/96215), [2](https://byjus.com/full-form/linux-full-form/), and [3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linux-full-form/#:%7E:text=LINUX%20stands%20for%20Lovable%20Intellect%20Not%20Using%20XP.&text=Linux%20is%20an%20open%2Dsource,mobile%20devices%2C%20and%20embedded%20devices.)

I used to think that the LINUX name is derived from its creator "Linus Torvalds". Please clarify this confusion. Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux#Naming The acronym you found is obviously a joke.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Haha. Thanks. I thought so. Just wanted to make sure of it. Please take this question down if you think it is non-sensical. :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misunderstanding

Comment: That last link can't even decide if it's LINUX (like an acronym), or Linux (not an acronym). Besides, the first versions of Linux came out in early 90's, and Linux 2.0 already in 1996, while Windows XP is from 2001, so what would that "Xp" there even refer to? [XP's in role-playing games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experience_point)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux is portmanteau of *Linus's UNIX*. Linus Torvalds, the author of Linux wanted to call it *Freax* (free/freak and x from “Unix”) but administrator of FTP server, where the first public version of Linux was published, named it “Linux” because this name was present in some source files. See also [Wikipedia page on Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux#Naming):

> Linus Torvalds had wanted to call his invention "Freax", a portmanteau of "free", "freak", and "x" (as an allusion to Unix). During the start of his work on the system, some of the project's makefiles included the name "Freax" for about half a year. Torvalds had already considered the name "Linux", but initially dismissed it as too egotistical.
>
> In order to facilitate development, the files were uploaded to the FTP server (ftp.funet.fi) of FUNET in September 1991. Ari Lemmke, Torvalds' coworker at the Helsinki University of Technology (HUT), who was one of the volunteer administrators for the FTP server at the time, did not think that "Freax" was a good name, so he named the project "Linux" on the server without consulting Torvalds. Later, however, Torvalds consented to "Linux".
>
> Author: Contributors of Wikipedia, [page link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux#Naming)